# sql server authentication using sa error connection string

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-2, connection

have anyone suggest me the right configuration of this connection string?

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AndroidEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;
         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connectionstring=data source=.\sqlexpress;initial 
         catalog=YOUR_DATABASE;user id=sa;password=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: "user id=sa;password=sa" - Really?

Comment: you want to use two connections.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Server are you using ? Please give more detials because Your password can be wrong , `password = sa` can't be there. it isn't a strong password for SQL Server, this can't exist unless you are using very old version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this:

```
<add name="HorovitzEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ManarData.csdl|res://*/ManarData.ssdl|res://*/ManarData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=YOUR_SQL_SERVER_INSTANCE_NAME;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
              providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```